# Is there a way to mock a procedural function from common.inc in a test without an external library?

Tags: 8, testing

I am trying to mock the `render()` function from `common.inc` in a test.

I am aware that `render()` could be substituted with a `renderer` service, but in this specific case I can't/couldn't refactor the code itself. Nor can I use an external lib for it.

Is there a way to do this in a native way, using PHPUnit only?

Comment: Got it, my problem could be solved by injecting fixtures into the `setUp` method of the test!

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/phpunit/unit-testing-more-complicated-drupal-classes

Comment: If you have found the answer, please post it as an answer here and accept it, to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution on this page: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/phpunit/unit-testing-more-complicated-drupal-classes

> You can mock a global function by adding fixtures in your test module.
>   Let's say that you need to mock base_path().
>
> 1. Simple go add a fixture in your testing src
> 2. Add a mock for function, for example, you can
>      define like above:
> 3. Simply use `require_once` on your setup and you get your mocked function available and replaceable only in the test you are requiring. Make sure to use `function_exists()` to check if the function you need to test isn't already available.

```
 /**
  * Overrides global function if not exists.
  *
  * @return string
  *   Base path mocked.
  */
  function base_path() {
    if (!function_exists('base_path')) {
      return '/';
    }
  }
```

In my case, I have used fixtures, as refactoring the code was out of question.

As the documentation says, I've created a mocked function in `tests/fixtures/function_name.php` and included the file into the `setUp()` method of the test with `require_once`. This way, I've had my own global function in the test's scope.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible and done in a handful of places in core. One example is [`TimeTest`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21Tests%21Component%21Datetime%21TimeTest.php/8.8.x). I am not 100% sure it is official, but I call it a shadow function.

The trick is to declare the procedural function in the same namespace as the caller.  As an example the `Drupal\Component\Datetime\Time` class has a method

```
public function getCurrentTime() {
  return time();
}
```

this calls out the PHP internal function `time()`.  `TimeTest` sets up

namespace Drupal\Component\Datetime;

```
/**
 * Shadow time() system call.
 *
 * @returns int
 */
function time() {
  return 12345678;
}
```

When PHP chases the scope for resolving a reference, it will check the current namespace first.  By declaring the namespace, the procedural function declaration ends up that namespace instead of the global one (`\`).  And since the test class only gets loaded during tests, you don't end up polluting the namespace with a bad function.